# Не получается выгрузить информацию о пользователе

Tags: java, android, api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные пользователя, но получается только `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`. А `sex`, `city`, `status` и т.д. не работают, хотя они вроде в методе `user.get()` должны присутствовать. В чем проблема может быть?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.MESSAGES, VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.STATUS, VKScope.PHOTOS};
    private TextView textView, textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fingerprints));

        VKSdk.login(this, scope);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get();
                request.useSystemLanguage = true;

                request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

                        VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
                        textView.setText(Integer.toString(user.id));
                        textView1.setText(user.first_name);
                        textView2.setText(user.last_name);
                        textView3.setText(user.sex);
                        textView4.setText(user.status);


                        Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.photo_400_orig);

                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Плохо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вроде же [четко написано](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), что чтобы получить поля кроме дефолтных их нужно отправить как параметры:

```
List<UserXtrCounters> users = vk.users().get(actor) 
    .userIds("1") 
    .fields(UserField.VERIFIED, UserField.SEX) 
    .lang(Lang.EN) 
    .execute();
```

Иначе он их не вернет, то есть вашем случае как-то так:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.users().fields(UserField.CITY, UserField.SEX).get();
```

**P.S.** Советую не злоупотреблять анонимными классами прямо в вызове функций, можно же их отдельно создавать, читать же код станет куда легче, например как-то так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.MESSAGES, VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.STATUS, VKScope.PHOTOS};
    private TextView textView, textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fingerprints));

        VKSdk.login(this, scope);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new MyVKCallback()) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private class MyVKCallback extends VKCallback<VKAccessToken> {

        @Override
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
            // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            VKRequest request = VKApi.users().fields(UserField.CITY, UserField.SEX).get();
            request.useSystemLanguage = true;

            request.executeWithListener(MyVKRequestListener());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Плохо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }

     private class MyVKRequestListener extends VKRequest.VKRequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

            VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(user.id));
            textView1.setText(user.first_name);
            textView2.setText(user.last_name);
            textView3.setText(user.sex);
            textView4.setText(user.status);


            Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.photo_400_orig);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее так `VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"id,first_name,last_name,photo_100,photo_max_orig,online,status,sex"));` но это все-равно не работает

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK?f=8.1.%20Request%20sample%20with%20user%20actor -  тут же показаны примеры как пишется код интеграции, почему не сделать по аналогии (хотя бы временно, чтобы проверить что данные возвращаются)?